# Set Adobe Reader as Default for .PDF documents in Mac OSX 10.8 via the Terminal

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, osx-mountain-lion

I would like to know how to set the .PDF file extension to be associated with Adobe Reader as the default program by setting this via the terminal in Mac OSX 10.8. My reasons for needing to this this via the terminal is due to the fact that i am applying this change on over thirty Macs. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Devon

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a user setting, you might need to do this for each user...

```
$ defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers -array-add '{LSHandlerContentType = "com.adobe.pdf"; LSHandlerRoleAll = "com.apple.preview";}'
```

Replace "com.apple.preview" by the CFBundleIdentifier of Adobe Reader (you will find it in the Info.plist of the application).

Be careful, if you run twice the command it might add several to the plist of com.apple.LaunchServices

The file is located here: `~/Library//Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist`

Comment: It may be necessary to rebuild the launch services domain for the local user after changing this setting (to get it to take effect immediately): `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain user`